# Rails Make Form Text Field Show Value From Model or Default Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datepicker

`Rails 5.0.4`  `ruby 2.5.1p57`

I have a form partial that has a date field. It uses the `datepicker` class.
  Currently, I have it set to display the current-date:

`<%= form_for(@weight) do |f| %>`

`<%= f.text_field :workout_date, { :size => 20, :type => 'date', :class => "date-picker", :readonly => false, :value => Date.today }  %>`

Because I use this form/partial on both the `new` and `edit` views, I would like it to show either the date in the model (for an edit) or the current date (for a new record).

I tried this:

`<%= f.text_field :workout_date, { :size => 20, :type => 'date', :class => "date-picker", :readonly => false, :value => @weight.workout_date.present? ? @weight.workout_date : Date.today }  %>`

But, this displays `09/01/2019`, when viewing the new form today `09/12/2019`.

Ideas on what I'm doing wrong?  Can this be done?

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Try using persisted? Instead of present?.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured this out.  In my migration to create the weights model:

`t.date "workout_date", :default => Date.today`   I created this on 09/01/2019, so the form is using this date.

`<%= form_for(@weight) do |f| %>`   I'm passing a weight object for a new record.  It must see that default date and use it.

Fix:  create a migration to removed that default date. OR, since the `new` model record does not have an `ID`, I can do this cheap-hack, which works, until I fix the model:

`<%= f.text_field :workout_date, { :size => 20, :type => 'date', :class => "date-picker", :readonly => false, :value => @weight.id.present? ? @weight.workout_date : Date.today } %>`

I also do not need the `.present?`.  It works without it.